# Is it possible to conditionally assign a Task to different Groups?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016, approval

I am trying to create an Approval process for time-off requests for my department. We have three different groups of employees with their own Approvers.

I've created Groups containing the approvers for each of the employee groups.
I have created the Approval Task, but I'm getting stuck on how to assign it to the different Groups of approvers.

I've tried everything I can think of, in terms of creating a workflow 
variable "Approvers" containing a group of users, and then setting the

'Start **Approval Process** on **Current Item** with **Variable:Approvers**"

accordingly. I am unsure what the start-task command is looking for - is it email addresses, user ID #s, or what?

So far, it looks like my only option is to create three different identical tasks assigned to their respective groups, and have the workflow conditionally start only the appropriate Task. But my larger goal is to scale this to my entire worksite, and that would involve creating a much larger number of identical tasks (and creating these is somewhat laborious) for each approval tree.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do not need to set a new variable to configure approvers. 
The start an approval process action can do that work for you.

Simply click on the link shows "these user", then use the people picker to add the groups of approver according to your requirements. In the pic below, i add the approvers and the designers group to be the participants of the approval process. You can add more member via typing name/email address or just select from the list below.

[image]